# How do the Postgres foreign key 'on update' and 'on delete' options work?

Tags: sql, database-design, postgresql, foreign-keys, cascade

Can anyone provide a clear explanation / example of what these functions do, and when it's appropriate to use them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Straight from [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)...

> We know that the foreign keys disallow creation of orders that do not relate to any products. But what if a product is removed after an order is created that references it? SQL allows you to handle that as well. Intuitively, we have a few options:
>
> Disallow deleting a referenced product
>
> Delete the orders as well
>
> Something else?

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
 product_no integer REFERENCES products ON DELETE RESTRICT,
 order_id integer REFERENCES orders ON DELETE CASCADE,
 quantity integer,
 PRIMARY KEY (product_no, order_id)
);
```

> Restricting and cascading deletes are the two most common options. RESTRICT prevents deletion of a referenced row. NO ACTION means that if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify anything. (The essential difference between these two choices is that NO ACTION allows the check to be deferred until later in the transaction, whereas RESTRICT does not.) CASCADE specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well. There are two other options: SET NULL and SET DEFAULT. These cause the referencing columns to be set to nulls or default values, respectively, when the referenced row is deleted. Note that these do not excuse you from observing any constraints. For example, if an action specifies SET DEFAULT but the default value would not satisfy the foreign key, the operation will fail.
>
> Analogous to ON DELETE there is also ON UPDATE which is invoked when a referenced column is changed (updated). The possible actions are the same.

**edit:** You might want to take a look at this related question: [When/Why to use Cascading in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297/whenwhy-to-use-cascading-in-sql-server). The concepts behind the question/answers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have a PostGreSQL database and I use On Delete when I have a user that I delete from the database and I need to delete it's information from other table. This ways I need to do only 1 delete and FK that has ON delete will delete information from other table.

You can do the same with ON Update. If you update the table and the field have a FK with On Update, if a change is made on the FK you will be noticed on the FK table.

Answer (score 0):

What Daok says is true... it can be rather convenient. On the other hand, having things happen automagically in the database can be a real problem, especially when it comes to eliminating data. It's possible that in the future someone will count on the fact that FKs usually prevent deletion of parents when there are children and not realize that your use of On Delete Cascade not only doesn't prevent deletion, it makes huge amounts of data in dozens of other tables go away thanks to a waterfall of cascading deletes.

@Arthur's comment.

The more frequently "hidden" things happen in the database the less likely it becomes that anyone will ever have a good handle on what is going on. Triggers (and this is essentially  a trigger) can cause my simple action of deleting a row, to have wide ranging consequences throughout my database. I issue a Delete statement and 17 tables are affected with cascades of triggers and constraints and none of this is immediately apparent to the issuer of the command. OTOH, If I place the deletion of the parent and all its children in a procedure then it is very easy and clear for anyone to see EXACTLY what is going to happen when I issue the command.

It has absolutely nothing to do with how well I design a database. It has everything to do with the operational issues introduced by triggers.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem if the schema is designed correctly.  usually childred (FKs) of data isn't really useful without its parent.

Comment: That's a reasonable statement. But the more things that occur without intent the less successful the database. see edits in answer above.

Comment: You have to decide if the DB is just a data dump for an application, or if the DB has value / meaning on its own. When a DB can operate without an app -- direct data load, direct query access etc. -- you must define the rules in the DB layer, because the app isn't there to do those things for you. In my experience, junior developers tend to treat the DB as controlled by an app, while senior developers (who have been burned too many times) design the DB to stand on its own. Remember, DBs can live on long after the app is gone. This is just the principle of encapsulation, applied to databases.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the method to do all the work, of the cascade delete or cascade update, you could simply write a warning message instead.  A lot easier than reinventing the wheel, and it makes it clear to the client (and new developers picking up the code)