# Should I use the CASCADE DELETE rule?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascade

> **Duplicate of: [When/Why to use Cascading in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59297/1288)**

I've always been too scared to use DELETE CASCADE, but as I get more confident (lazy :D), I'm thinking how bad can it be, is it best practise to use it or should I avoid it and clean up my foreign keys etc the old fashioned way (with stored procedures)?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

ON DELETE CASCADE is fine, but only when the dependent rows are really a logical extension of the row being deleted.  For example, it's OK for DELETE ORDERS to delete the associated ORDER_LINES because clearly you want to delete this order, which consists of a header and some lines.  On the other hand, DELETE CUSTOMER should not delete the associated ORDERS because ORDERS are important in their own right, they are not just attributes of a customer.

One way to think about this is: if I issue DELETE X and it also deletes Y, will I be happy or unhappy?  And if I issue DELETE X and am told "cannot delete X because Y exists" will I be glad of the protection, or irritated at the inconvenience?

Comment: Just curious, if customer doesn't exist what good will ORDER entry do?

Comment: Customer **will** exist, because the delete of customer will fail if we aren't allowing cascade to order.

Comment: @codersofthedark One real-world scenario is that if an admin happens to delete a user by mistake, it shouldn't delete the orders, or the whole accounting department will go for a toss.

Answer (score 15):

I prefer having control over exactly what is deleted (by explicitly declaring it), so I generally opt to delete via stored procedures, and not to use cascading deletes.