# How to delete rows in tables that contain foreign keys to other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose there is a main table containing a primary key and there is another table which contains a foreign key to this main table. So if we delete the row of main table it will delete the child table also.

How do I write this query?

Comment: @pradeep: what database are you using?

Comment: database used by me: sql sever 2008

Comment: i want simple Query i don't want to use store procedure

Comment: i dont think there is a simpler version than what Lieven has mentioned below. Just to clarify, the ON CASCADE DELETE option is not a part of the query, its a part of your Child table DDL statement. Refer http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/General/using_constraints.htm for an example

Answer (score 34):

First, as a one-time data-scrubbing exercise, delete the orphaned rows e.g.

```
DELETE 
  FROM ReferencingTable 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM MainTable AS T1
                    WHERE T1.pk_col_1 = ReferencingTable.pk_col_1
                  );
```

Second, as a one-time schema-alteration exercise, add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` referential action to the foreign key on the referencing table e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE ReferencingTable DROP 
   CONSTRAINT fk__ReferencingTable__MainTable;

ALTER TABLE ReferencingTable ADD 
   CONSTRAINT fk__ReferencingTable__MainTable 
      FOREIGN KEY (pk_col_1)
      REFERENCES MainTable (pk_col_1)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then, forevermore, rows in the referencing tables will automatically be deleted when their referenced row is deleted.

Answer (score 26):

From your question, I think it is safe to assume you have [CASCADING DELETES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278392/should-i-use-the-cascade-delete-rule) turned on.
All that is needed in that case is

```
DELETE FROM MainTable
WHERE PrimaryKey = ???
```

You database engine will take care of deleting the corresponding referencing records.

Comment: In oracle, you will first  need to delete the `dependencies` and then delete the parent.

Comment: And what will happen if the referenced table is a  main table for another tables and there are a FK with Delete rule: No Action. Does the server will allow to delete record from current MainTable where we set Delete rule to: Cascade? Thanks

Comment: @LevZ - No, it won't. You'll have to either remove the FK constraint or turn the child table's cascading deletes on.

Answer (score 13):

You can alter a foreign key constraint with delete cascade option as shown below. This will delete chind table rows related to master table rows when deleted.

```
ALTER TABLE MasterTable
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_xyz 
FOREIGN KEY (xyz) 
REFERENCES ChildTable (xyz) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: This is great however not always a solution when supporting low SQLite versions which may be the case for example in supporting Android API 4 which only ships with an SQLite just prior to them adding Foreign key support.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiply rows to delete and you don't want to alter the structure of your tables
you can use cursor.
1-You first need to select rows to delete(in a cursor)
2-Then for each row in the cursor you delete the referencing rows and after that delete the row him self.

Ex:

```
--id is primary key of MainTable
    declare @id int
    set @id = 1
    declare theMain cursor for select FK from MainTable where MainID = @id
    declare @fk_Id int
    open theMain
    fetch next from theMain into @fk_Id
    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
        --fkid is the foreign key 
        --Must delete from Main Table first then child.
        delete from MainTable where fkid = @fk_Id
        delete from ReferencingTable where fkid = @fk_Id
        fetch next from theMain into @fk_Id
    end
    close theMain
    deallocate theMain
```

hope is useful

Comment: While this works, if you're using T-SQL the performance on cursors is really bad.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delete all the rows, you can use truncate with cascade:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE products CASCADE;
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to work in T-SQL

Answer (score -3):

Need to set the foreign key option as on **delete cascade**...
in tables which contains foreign key columns.... It need to set at the time of table creation or add later using ALTER table

Comment: And why post something that was already been given in other answers yet again?