# how to join more than 2 table using sql Query?

Tags: sql

suppose  i have more than 2 table and i want to join the specific column to be join .for this what is query?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Abe, in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656099/how-to-delete-rows-in-tables-that-contain-foreign-keys-to-other-tables pradeep confirms that he is using SQLServer 2008.

Comment: I hereby award you the elusive "Detective" badge.

Answer (score 11):

example:

```
select a.column1, a.column2, b.whatever, c.hello
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.keyfield = b.keyfield
join table3 c on a.keyfield = c.keyfield
```

If you wanted all records from table1 even without a matching record in another table, then the join should be "left join" instead.