# Delete SQL row and all dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, adventureworks

If I want to delete 1 person in "AdventureWorks2017" data base, for example:

```
DELETE FROM [Person].[Person] WHERE BusinessEntityID = 1
```

I know I have to make sure that all dependencies to that person are removed before I can do it.

Because `Person.Person` has many dependencies and may have 7 levels of dependencies (like for `[Sales].[SalesOrderHeaderSalesReason]`), what would be the best way to do it?

How do i write the db script to delete it and all that person’s dependencies.

Comment: Using cascading delete constraints.  The database will do this automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all dependent rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317894/how-to-delete-all-dependent-rows)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server

Comment: either with an `instead of trigger` or by setting `cascade delete` on

Comment: "Best way"? I'm a fan of putting that sort of logic in a stored procedure. It can delete all of the related rows within the context of a single transaction. It allows you to revoke the permissions that allow users to delete rows directly from the tables involved so that they must use your SP, provides a place to do additional authorization checks, logging, ... . Mistakes can propagate with remarkable speed when a cascade is triggered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use cascade delete with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server)