# How to delete a row in a table and all its foreign key relationships with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have table called "Categories"
[image]

Which has a relationship with this table

[image]

How can I for a example delete the "ForumTest" category and all the threads related to it in the second table?

EDIT: This is my current code that only works with categories without relationships

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteCategory(int? id)
{
    Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);

    db.Threads.RemoveRange(category.Threads);
    db.Categories.Remove(category);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Categories");
}
```

Comment: is this code first or what ? Can you share your code also?

Comment: this will help :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656099/how-to-delete-rows-in-tables-that-contain-foreign-keys-to-other-tables

Comment: You want to do this one time or every time You delete a row from Catagories?

Comment: I added my current code.

Comment: hope data base first no ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to config your relationship with [cascading delete](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx). Override `OnModelCreating` method in your context and add this:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Thread>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Category)
    .WithMany(r => r.Threads)
    .HasForeignKey(s=>s.CategoryId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);

db.Threads.RemoveRange(category.Threads);
db.Categories.Remove(category);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**After this Remove all related table data like.**

```
var categoryDetail = relatedtable.Find(id);


    db.relatedtable.RemoveAll(categoryDetail);
    db.SaveChanges();
```