# Enabling view of relational database values in microsoft access (2007)

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a relational database for a friend and I have never used MS Access before.  I am trying to make it so that the related values are shown on a table view rather than the numeric representation.  For example, instead of

```
[1][2242], [2][443]
```

I would like

```
[1][John Smith], [2][Marilyn Monroe]
```

(the first value being the primary key and the second being the value linked to another table).

I have read [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/create-edit-or-delete-a-relationship-HA010072597.aspx) page about creating relationships between tables but I am still having trouble "viewing" the linked values.  Microsoft Access is going to be the only way my friend is going to be viewing these results so that is why it is important to be able to see the correct values.

I have made relational databases before but only with traditional PHP and SQL and so I know what I need to do but I cannot seem to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not be [misled into creating lookup values in tables](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm). Create a form and add comboboxes to display the data from the related table, or use queries.

For example: [create form to add records in multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131211/create-form-to-add-records-in-multiple-tables/12132196#12132196)

Or

```
 SELECT Id, Fullname FROM Table1
 INNER JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.FKID = Table2.ID
```

You can create the [relationships visually in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624976/synchronize-data-in-two-database-table-upon-deletion/14626305#14626305). You can also build queries in the query design window.