# How to create foreign key so when we delete parent value in child will be updated to null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new in T-SQL please help:
I have two tables

```
User
  Id
  Name

History
  Id
  Result
  UserId
```

How to create relationship so once I delete User from User table the History table will be updated for the column UserId to NULL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `on delete set null` like this

```
ALTER TABLE USERS 
ADD CONSTRAINT Users_ThemeID_FK 
FOREIGN KEY (ThemeID) REFERENCES Themes(ThemeID) 
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted!!!! You are the best! I will accept this answer in 3 minutes when it will be available

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.History ADD CONSTRAINT
    FK_History_User FOREIGN KEY
    (
    UserID
    ) REFERENCES dbo.[User]
    (
    ID
    ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION 
     ON DELETE  SET NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to turn on [Cascading deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278392/should-i-use-the-cascade-delete-rule), then setup a pK relationship then you just use regular Delete syntax like `Delete From Table Where PK =`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the action on the FK relationship to set to null:

```
-- Create FK relationship
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = N'FK_EmpEducation_Employees' AND [type] = 'F')
ALTER TABLE EmpEducation
DROP Constraint FK_EmpEducation_Employees
GO

ALTER TABLE EmpEducation
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EmpEducation_Employees]
FOREIGN KEY (empno)REFERENCES employees(empno)
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
GO
```

See Here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/