# Linq to SQL: delete record with generic type method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm creating synchronization system for SQL Server database.

```
    public void UpdateTable<T>(List<T> current, List<T> changed) where T : class
    {
        var deletedRecords = current.Except(changed);
        foreach (T entity in deletedRecords)
        {
            _context.GetTable<T>().DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
        }
        _context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

But on `DeleteOnSubmit` operation it fails with `InvalidOperationException: Unable to remove an embedded object.`

Database was designed with `CASCADE` delete operation. What's wrong? Thank you!

Comment: If you are using a static (shared) context... DONT!

Comment: You may want to check this out: [When/Why to use Cascading in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297/when-why-to-use-cascading-in-sql-server) and [Should I use the CASCADE DELETE rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278392/should-i-use-the-cascade-delete-rule).

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240256/Generic-Class-to-Perform-Insert-Update-Get-Delete) post?. In this example, it creates a **generic Interface** with a type T which inherits from **class**. This interface exposes the method *Delete(T Item)* which does something similar than what you did. The problem could be that you need to perform a *db.SubmitChanges()* for each object but I'm not really sure. So, I suggest to call this method for each object in your **deletedRecords** list. Hope it helps!

```
 // Deletes the data values in the LINQ to SQL generated class.
    public virtual bool Delete(T Item)
    {
        using (TestDBContext db = new TestDBContext())
        {
            db.GetTable<T>().DeleteOnSubmit(Item);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```