# Delete from table without affecting foreign value

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, cascade

When I want to delete a user, I need NOT to delete from companies. The 2 entities are linked with another which contains user id and company id.

Here is my annotations in the entity in which I link user and company ( could have done it otherwise but there are some other attributes:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\ManagementBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="uc", cascade={"persist"})
private $user;


@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\ManagementBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="uc", cascade={"persist"})
 private $compani;
```

When I delete with `EmtityManager()->remove($user);` it deletes anything related to this user.
Couldn't find anything that could help me.

Comment: Check your database and see if you have cascading deletes turned on at the database level.  The code you've shown shouldn't cause cascading deletes on its own.

Comment: Sorry for the late, any instructions on how to do that ?

Comment: Run the following query via the MySQL command line: `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>`.  You should be able to see any existing constraints.  If you see `ON CASCADE DELETE`, that means that the database is enforcing the deletes itself.

Comment: there is  no ON CASCADE DELETE in query result.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have [CASCADING DELETES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278392/should-i-use-the-cascade-delete-rule) turned on.
All that is needed in that case is

```
DELETE FROM MainTable
WHERE PrimaryKey = ???
```

You database engine will take care of deleting the corresponding referencing records.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question - his deletes are currently cascading, but he doesn't want them to (at least not in this direction).

Comment: he's right, you've misunderstood me, my deletes are currently cascading, and i don't want them to in both directions x)