# Should I let JPA or the database cascade deletions?

Tags: sql, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, cascading-deletes

Let's say we have two entities, A and B. B has a many-to-one relationship to A like follows:

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="a_id")
  private List<B> children;
}

@Entity
public class B {
  private String data;
}
```

Now, I want to delete the `A` object and cascade the deletions to all its children `B`. There are two ways to do this:

1. Add `cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true` to the OneToMany annotation, letting JPA remove all children before removing the A-object from the database.
2. Leave the classes as they are and simply let the database cascade the deletion.

Is there any problem with using the later option? Will it cause the Entity Manager to keep references to already deleted objects? My reason for choosing option two over one is that option one generates n+1 SQL queries for a removal, which can take a prolonged time when object A contains a lot of children, while option two only generates a single SQL query and then moves on happily. Is there any "best practice" regarding this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Cascading Deletes/Updates using JPA or Inside of Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554750/cascading-deletes-updates-using-jpa-or-inside-of-database)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In EclipseLink you can use both if you use the `@CascadeOnDelete` annotation. EclipseLink will also generate the cascade DDL for you.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DeleteCascade

This optimizes the deletion by letting the database do it, but also maintains the cache and the persistence unit by removing the objects.

Note that `orphanRemoval=true` will also delete objects removed from the collection, which the database cascade constraint will not do for you, so having the rules in JPA is still necessary.  There are also some relationships that the database cannot handle deletion for, as the database can only cascade in the inverse direction of the constraint, a `OneToOne` with a foreign key, or a `OneToMany` with a join table cannot be cascaded on the database.

Comment: Looks what I was looking for! Too bad it's vendor specific, but it will have to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I'd prefer the database. Why?

- The database is probably a lot faster doing this
- The database should be the primary place to hold integrity and relationship information. JPA is just reflecting that information
- If you're connecting with a different application / platform (i.e. without JPA), you can still cascadingly delete your records, which helps increase data integrity

Comment: I agree with your points, but are you sure that the entity manager should not be notified that a number of objects have been removed? Maybe the worst case scenario is that some dead objects are cached (but normally not accessible since this would be through the parent object which is removed) for a few minutes. Point two and three can be ignored if I specify cascade both in the database aswell as in JPA. What do you think of this option?

Comment: You are right, sorry, I hadn't thoroughly read your question. I guess that depends on the JPA implementation. Probably, you can specify cascading deletes both in your database AND in your JPA annotated classes. A good implementation should reflect this by refreshing its caches. But the last time I used JPA (with Hibernate, quite some time ago), this clearly wasn't the case. The solution was to disable all caching...

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9925761/59015) raises some really strong arguments about why it should be JPA that handles the cascade, not the database.

Here's the relevant quote:

> ...if you would make cascades on database, and not declare them in
>   Hibernate (for performance issues) you could in some circumstances get
>   errors. This is because Hibernate stores entities in its session
>   cache, so it would not know about database deleting something in
>   cascade.
>
> When you use second-level cache, your situation is even worse, because
>   this cache lives longer than session and such changes on db-side will
>   be invisible to other sessions as long old values are stored in this
>   cache.