# Raw SQL in .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql, .net-core

I have this problem: I need to execute raw SQL from my .NET Core app. So I have this code

```
var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
var cmd = new SqlCommand
{
    CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Candidates WHERE id = " + model.CandidateId,
    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
    Connection = sqlConnection1
};

sqlConnection1.Open();
var wantedRow = cmd.ExecuteReader();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

I can't access the data in wantedRow...
(When I use Entity Framework this query works, but I can't use Entity Framework). Is it possible in .NET Core?

Comment: What error do you receive ?

Comment: I don't receive an error, I receive SqlDataReader object and wantedRow.GetString() gives me Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Comment: @MacakM This code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, you need to parameterize your query. You're also not handling your [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects correctly. Those need to be wrapped in a using statement.

Comment: The code above doesn't give an error. When I tried some bad way to obtain the data, then I got an error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**First**, your code is an open door for [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings.

**Second**, use the `using` statement for everything that implements the IDisposable interface. In this case - connection, command and reader.

**Third**, getting the reader is just a part of the job. You still need to use `reader.Read()` and get the values.

```
using(var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
{ 
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand()
    {
        CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Candidates WHERE id = @id",
        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        Connection = sqlConnection1
    })
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = model.CandidateId
        sqlConnection1.Open();

        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                var id = reader[0];
                var whatEver = reader[1];
                // get the rest of the columns you need the same way
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to make an open door to SQL Injection (that's why I don't use Entity Framework). I also know about using, but firstly I wanted a code that works, then write usings. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I want to use this app to show my students how they can do SQL Injection :) But it is surprisingly difficult now to make an app that is vulnerable to SQL Injection when we have great ORM frameworks :D

Comment: Yes but in .NET Core I can't use SqlDataAdapter and with other classes I don't have much experience

Comment: This is my opinion - you can ignore it - but I believe that by accepting the answer you accepted without elaborating on the question itself that you are looking for vulnerable code you are basically telling the future readers that it's a better answer, and even though they might answer your specific need better then this one, most future readers will probably not benefit from a code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection. I beleive that to the question as posted, my answer is the the best of the current answers as it's the most complete and adresses both Sql injection and the using statement.

Comment: Yes I think about it 20 minutes... I think that you are right - answer that is accepted now was helpful for me because it was the only info I needed, but for the future readers your answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try using as below and try accessing the SQLDataReader :

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ExecuteReader should return you SqlDataReader, which means you should do something like

```
while(wantedRow.Read())
{
    var aValue = wantedRow[0].Value;
}
```