# business logic in stored procedures vs. middle layer

Tags: postgresql, web-services, database-design, middleware

I'd like to use Postgres as web api storage backend. I certainly need (at least some) glue code to implement my REST interface (and/or WebSocket). I think about two options:

1. Implement most of the business logic as stored procedures, PL/SQL while using a very thin middle layer to handle the REST/websocket part.
2. middle layer implements most of the business logic, and reach Pg over it's abstract DB interface.

My question is what are the possible benefits/hindrances of the above designs compared to each other regarding flexibility, scalability, maintainability and availability?

I don't really care about the exact middle layer implementation (it can be either php, node.js, python or whatever), I'm interested in the benefits and pitfalls of the actual architectural design choice.

I'm aware of that I lose some flexibility by choosing (1) since it would be difficult to port the system to other than maybe oracle, and my users will be bound to postgres. In my case it's not very important, the database intended to be an integral part of the system anyway.

I'm especially interested in the benefits lost in case of choosing (2), and  possible pitfalls of either case.

Comment: Refer another thread for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171769/when-should-i-use-stored-procedures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both options have their benefits and drawbacks.
(2) approach is good and known. Most simple applications and web services are using it. But sometimes, using stored procedure is much better than (2). 
Here is some examples which, IMHO, are good to implement with stored procedures:

- tracking changes of rows. I.e you have some table with items that are regularly updated and you want to have another table with all changes and dates of that changes for every item.
- custom algorithms, if your functions can be used as expressions for indexing data.
- you want to share some logic between several micro-services. If every micro-service are implemented using a different language, you have to re-implement some parts of the business logic for every language and micro-service. Using stored procedures obviously can help to avoid this.

Some benefits of (2) approach (with some "however" of course to confuse you :D):

- You can use your favorite programing language to write business logic.
  However: in (1) approach you can write procedures using pl/v8 or pl/php or pl/python or pl/whatever extension using your favorite language.
- maintaning code is more easy than maintaining stored procedures.
  However: there is some good methods to avoid such headaches with code maintenance. I.e: migrations, which is a good thing for every approach.
  Also, you can put your functions into your own namespace, so to reinstall re-deploy procedures into database you have to just drop and re-create this namespace, not each function. This can be done with simple script.
- you can use various ORM's to query data and got abstraction layers which can have much more complex logic and inheritance logic. In (1) it would be hard to use OOP patterns. 
  I think this is the most powerful argument against (1) approach, and I can't add any 'however' to this.