# Which is good practice and why, if I can achieve same functionality with stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using (var db = new PoContext())
{
    var maxSrno = db.poDtInfo.Where(x => x.Job_Code_Id == Convert.ToInt16(jobcodeID)).Select(x => x.Po_Dt_Id).Max();
    if (maxSrno == null)
        maxSrno = jobcodeID + 102 + 10000001;
    else
        maxSrno = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(maxSrno) + 1).ToString();  //Convert.ToInt64(maxSrno) + 1 .ToString();
    var newPo = new PoDtInfo();
    JsonConvert.PopulateObject(values, newPo);
    newPo.Po_Dt_Id = maxSrno;
    db.poDtInfo.Add(newPo);
    db.SaveChanges();
    result = true;
}
```

Comment: Please wrap your code in the code block

Comment: Welcome.  Please don't just post a code listing into a question without any actual question.  [ask].  You may [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52713276/edit) your question to improve it.  Good luck

Comment: Are you using a SQL Server database?  SQL Server is multi-threaded so if you have a micro that has more than one core the Server stored procedure will always be faster than with c# code.

Comment: To expand on the comments above please checkout the guidelines of SO [here's an article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more familiar with SO and what is expected.

Comment: Have you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171769/when-should-i-use-stored-procedures

Answer (score 1):

Disadvantages of stored procedures

- Stored procedures are hard to maintain. It's much harder to refactor to use e.g. a specific pattern or use dependency injection.
- They are hard to debug.
- It's harder if not impossible to unit test.
- It's harder to have control over versions and deployment.
- It's harder to control localization (if only to generate localized error messages).
- Additionally, they integrate bad into a software. If you want to get .NET events, exceptions, write to log files and the like.
- It's harder or impossible to use your neat tool library you wrote in C# (like project specific string handling, specific data types, date and time stuff and so on)

Advantages of stored procedures

- Stored procedures could be faster. Only in cases when there is a lot of data that would have to be loaded to another machine to be processed.

Because of the high number of disadvantages I would only use stored procedures when you have to solve performance problems that cannot be solved in another way. Note: I've written software for a large Database-centric client-server application and never had to write a single stored procedure.

Comment: Many of your listed disadvantages are "arguable", to say the least. I.e. in our environment, database schemas and static data are source controlled alongside any other code and our deployments are as automated as the code that interacts *with* the DB. Many of our DBs do also have unit tests.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yeah, that's why it's "harder", not impossible. It means, you need to invest additional effort. That's not that much arguable. You could argue whether it is worth the effort.

Comment: But many of them are as true for e.g. C# as they are for SQL. They're all hard *if you haven't learned how to do them* in *any language or technology*.