# Auto increment isn't correct when running two instances

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have 2 Instances of the below code running, which connects to System.Data.SQLite database. When I insert a row into the database using any one instance, the auto incremented value (ID) is not proper when read from other instance. What is the reason behind this?

```vb
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Public Class Form1
    Public cnn As SQLiteConnection
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cnn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\\abc\xx\x_backup.db;Password=password;Connect Timeout=55;FailIfMissing=True")
        cnn.ParseViaFramework = True
        cnn.Open()
    End Sub
    Public Function inserttoTable(ByVal sql As String) As DataTable

         Try
            sql = "SELECT max(ID) FROM joblog;"
            Dim mycommand As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(cnn)
            mycommand.CommandText = sql
            MsgBox(mycommand.ExecuteScalar)
            sql = "INSERT INTO joblog (jobid) VALUES (123);"

            mycommand = New SQLiteCommand(cnn)
            mycommand.CommandText = sql
            MsgBox(mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery())
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Comment: First, your sql statements should be made into stored procedures (always). Second, you have two SQL statements in one INSERT function. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ciammarino `should be made into stored procedures (always)` why should they; Microsoft did leave a property for this called `CommandType` to either choose text and or stored procedure. What's wrong with assigning different strings to the same variable *in this case*; `So that will leave you with wonky results`, can you explain *wonky results*?

Comment: Why to use stored procedures: Separation of concerns, abstraction, security, best practices, there are a laundry list of reasons why to use SPs, see [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171769/when-should-i-use-stored-procedures).

Comment: @ciammarino I know what the reasons are and SP's are definitely good to use, my point is, why use one here; you mentioned it should be. If it isn't made into one, do you think making it a stored procedure will address the OP issue here?

Comment: Fair enough, no I don't. I also did not mean to shift the focus of the question to the issue of SPs. I was only letting you know it can be important.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to insert a JobID into the table and then retrieve the row for the JobID you just inserted?

Comment: @ciammarino it's fine, you did bring up a good recommendation, using SP's, this is great, but TBH isn't the concern and or issue here.

Comment: @ciammarino , my requirement is to use open connection only once in the lifetime of a single instance and keep on using it to insert a row . Similarly, to insert row to same db in other instance (again with its own connection for one lifetime). I need them to insert with proper auto-increment values .

Comment: i do not want to use WAL ,or close and open connections after every insert.

Comment: I guess you want to use `CInt(mycommand.ExecuteScalar) + 1` for the new ID. Is that right? If so, does your table not automatically increment the ID when a new row is inserted (is it a PrimaryKey)?

Comment: @ITresearcher You stated: "When I insert a row into the database using any one instance, the auto incremented value (ID) is not proper when read from other instance." Would you please elaborate on what you mean by that (i.e. expected vs. actual behavior)?

Comment: @entpnerd ;assume current id (auto incremented value) is 150 .When instance A inserts 3 rows , id created is say 151 ,152,153;  then when instance B inserts a row , id created should be 154, but i sometime get 151 again.

Comment: @ITresearcher  Are you starting an explicit transaction anywhere in the code (not shared in the question)?

Comment: Have you read [this about multiple connections](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5), especially on a Windows machine and particular file systems?

Comment: @CPerkins No explicit transaction done. Also sometimes(when another application also inserts row) we get "UNIQUE constraint failed" error to "ID" column (which is AUTO-INCREMENT) i.e AUTO-INCREMENT is not working for insert. Also if we try to read maximum ID, it doesn't return last inserted ID.

Comment: @CPerkins yes,only one process is making changes to the database at a moment in time

Comment: @ITresearcher  Please clarify.  How does "two instances" not equate to "two processes"?  On the operating system level, two instances should be two processes.  The assumption here is that the "two instances" are running concurrently.  If that is not the case, more detail is needed.

Comment: @CPerkins two instances are same as two processes, and they are running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

> When i insert a row into the database using any one instance ,the auto incremented value(ID) is not proper when read from other instance

I *suspect it's because your connections and commands aren't closed/disposed* so they are left open.

Best advice for connection is to use it and then close/dispose of it. Same goes for commands, make sure they are disposed.

Here's one way to do this:

```vb
 Dim intReturn As Integer
 sql = "SELECT max(ID) FROM joblog;"

 ' First query to get your scalar return value
 Using cnn As New New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\\abc\xx\x_backup.db;Password=password;Connect Timeout=55;FailIfMissing=True")
    Using mycommand As New SQLiteCommand(sql, cnn)
       cnn.ParseViaFramework = True
       cnn.Open()

       intReturn = mycommand.ExecuteScalar
       MessageBox.Show(intReturn)

    End Using
 End Using

 ' Second query to actually do the insert
 sql = "INSERT INTO joblog (jobid) VALUES (123);"
 Using cnn As New New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\\abc\xx\x_backup.db;Password=password;Connect Timeout=55;FailIfMissing=True")
    Using mycommand As New SQLiteCommand(sql, cnn)
       cnn.ParseViaFramework = True
       cnn.Open()

       intReturn = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       MessageBox.Show("Records affected " & intReturn)

    End Using
 End Using
```

On another note, look into using [SQL Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteparameter?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0), otherwise you may be prone to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: "I suspect it's because your connections and commands aren't closed/disposed so they are left open." so sqlite cannot handle db when two instances have open connections ?

Comment: @IT researcher It locks the whole database when writing... It *could* technically, but its a race condition, I myself have seen this.

Answer (score 0):

The function I used is somewhat equivalent to Scope_Identity in Sql Server. I do not have an SqLite database hanging around so I couldn't test. I am not sure if you can chain commands in SqLite but if not just make 2 separate queries. The `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row in the result set which is the number you want.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim NewID As Long
    Using cn As New SQLiteConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO joblog (jobid) VALUES (123); Select last_insert_rowid()")
            NewID = CLng(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show($"The new ID is {NewID}")
End Sub
```

Comment: i do not want to close and open connections after every insert .

Comment: ADO.net handles connection pooling. I cannot see a reason not to close it. If you want to do a batch update use a DataAdapter.Update.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that you should not use shared sqlite database file, it is not stable, and the database file can easily be corrupted.Using mariadb/postgresql is a better idea.

I think your problem is about transaction, you should commit your changes manually to update the database file immediately after updating.

```
1. SQLiteTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
2. select max(id), insert...
3. trans.commit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I found this same problem.  Here's how I solved it.  I created a table in MS SQL Server called "SeqNo".  Here's the code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SeqNo](
    [SeqNoCode] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SeqNo] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SeqNo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SeqNoCode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and then used the following VB.Net function to retrieve the next seq no.

```
   Public Function NextSeqNo(ByVal SeqNoCode As String) As Long
        Dim strSQL As String = "DECLARE @SeqNo bigint;" & vbCrLf &
            "SET NOCOUNT ON;" & vbCrLf &
            "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" & vbCrLf &
            "IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SeqNo WHERE SeqNoCode = '" & SeqNoCode & "') = 0" & vbCrLf &
                "INSERT INTO SeqNo (SeqNoCode, SeqNo) VALUES ('" & SeqNoCode & "', 0);" & vbCrLf &
            "SELECT @SeqNo = SeqNo FROM SeqNo WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE SeqNoCode = '" & SeqNoCode & "'" & vbCrLf &
            "SET @SeqNo = @SeqNo + 1" & vbCrLf &
            "UPDATE SeqNo SET SeqNo = @SeqNo WHERE SeqNoCode = '" & SeqNoCode & "'" & vbCrLf &
            "COMMIT TRANSACTION" & vbCrLf &
            "SELECT @SeqNo"
        Dim scmdNextSeqNo As New SqlCommand(strSQL, GlobalVars.SQLConnection)
        Dim objNextSeqNo As Object = scmdNextSeqNo.ExecuteScalar
        Return CLng(objNextSeqNo)
    End Function
```

Notice that it incorporates a transaction and that locks the table, increments the sequence number and then unlocks the table.  Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.