# soft delete or hard delete good for eCommerce

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, archive

I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549839/are-soft-deletes-a-good-idea) post but I am concerned the best solution for eCommerce site

Our scenario:

**Product table**

```
ProductID Name Price
```

**OrderDetails table**

```
OrderID ProductID
```

OrderDetails table has `FK` ProductID referrenced to ProductID of Product table

once product has been deleted, how are you going to display the historical order report?

**Options:**

soft delete disadvantage - it affects db storage performance

hard delete disadvantage - need extra join query while taking report

Any help would be great.

Comment: Soft delete would be the better way. In other way, you can have a separate table to hold historical data and hard delete it from original table.

Comment: @viki888 thanks for it but currently we are planning to use soft delete with IsDeleted and DeletedDate fields.In future if needed we would move to hard delete and archive the data in different table.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go with soft delete. Especially if in an e-commerce context.

How about storing deleted products in an `ArchivedProduct` table and then doing the following:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
OrderDetails RIGHT JOIN Product ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Product.ProductID
UNION ALL
SELECT
*
FROM
OrderDetails RIGHT JOIN ArchivedProduct ON OrderDetails.ProductID = ArchivedProduct.ProductID
```

When you say

> it affects db storage performance

Yes, there is an overhead in terms of performance which is entirely dependent upon the size of the 3 tables.

If at a later stage you wanted to increase the performance of the query, you could either wipe out some of the previously "deleted" products from the `ArchivedProduct` table based on your own considerations (for example, all products inserted prior to ...) or add some constraints to the second `SELECT` statement. You'd still be in a safer position than with a hard delete.