# Deleting tables with referential integrity - get REFERENCE constraint

Tags: sql-server

I want to delete a User (parent table) which has blog comment(s) and blog comment reply(s)

I have it coded to 1st delete the BlogCommentReply (child to the BlogComment), then the BlogComment (parent to BlogCommentReply), then the user (parent to both).

I get the error:

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_BlogCommentReply_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "DBGbngDev", table "dbo.BlogCommentReply", column 'UserId'.

I have FK keys on the BlogCommentReply and BlogComment tables.

---

1.) Did I create the table structure correctly?
2.) Do I need cascades - why?
3.) Is the delete code order correct?
_ I am of the belief that the parent table cannot be deleted until the
children are deleted first. Is that correct?

---

Table creates:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
   [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- PK
   other columns....      
   CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
   (
     [UserId] ASC
   ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = 
           ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
          ) ON [PRIMARY]
   GO
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment]
(
  [BlogCommentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,      -- PK      
  [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,                           -- FK
  other columns....   
  CONSTRAINT [PK_BlogComment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
    [BlogCommentId] ASC
  ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
     ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
         ) ON [PRIMARY]
  GO

  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogComment] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogComment_UserId] FOREIGN 
  KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
  GO
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply]
(
  [BlogCommentReplyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- PK      
  [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,                           -- FK
  [BlogCommentId] [int] NOT NULL,                    -- FK    
  other columns.... 
  CONSTRAINT [PK_BlogCommentReply] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
     [BlogCommentReplyId] ASC
  ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = 
           ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
         ) ON [PRIMARY]
  GO

  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_UserId] FOREIGN 
  KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
  GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BlogCommentReply] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_BlogCommentReply_BlogCommentId] 
 FOREIGN KEY([BlogCommentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BlogComment] ([BlogCommentId])
 GO
```

---

Stored procedure (simplified for discussion) that does the deletes:

```
DELETE dbo.BlogCommentReply
FROM dbo.BlogComment a
WHERE ( BlogCommentReply.BlogCommentId = a.BlogCommentId AND BlogCommentReply.UserId = @a_UserId )

DELETE dbo.BlogComment
WHERE UserId = @a_UserId

DELETE dbo.[User]
WHERE ( UserId = @a_UserId )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your FK's are doing their jobs and preventing you from creating orphaned rows when deleting data from `BlogCommentReply`.

Your first `DELETE` from `BlogCommentReply` can be rewritten as two statements to make work correctly:

```
-- Remove replies added by the deleted user
DELETE
  FROM  dbo.BlogCommentReply
  WHERE (UserId = @a_UserId)

-- Remove blog comment replies added by other users creating replies to a comment made by the deleted user
DELETE
  FROM  dbo.BlogCommentReply
  WHERE (BlogCommentId IN (
                          SELECT  BlogCommentId
                            FROM  BlogComment
                            WHERE (UserId = @a_UserId)
                          ))
```

In the first statement you are simply trying to delete rows from `BlogCommentReply` that use a FK to the `User` table.

In the second statement you delete any reply to a blog comment that will be deleted.

In response to your specific questions:

**1. Did I create the table structure correctly?**

> It looks fine although there are several ways to achieve the same.

**2. Do I need cascades - why?**

> No.  Cascade deletes reek of poor design and lazy development.  Try to
> avoid them (note this is an *opinion* not a statement of fact).
>
> There are some interesting points in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59297/when-why-to-use-cascading-in-sql-server).

**3. Is the delete code order correct?**

> Yes, delete from the tables in order of key precidence.

**4. I am of the belief that the parent table cannot be deleted until the children are deleted first. Is that correct?**

> Yes indeed, without cascaded deletes that is correct and, in your
> case, the error thrown shows that the referential integrity of the
> database is sound.

Comment: Thanks..any insight into this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67118480/how-to-create-a-list-within-a-list-in-sql-temp-table